# SQLite Error inserting on new ContentValues();

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this issue:

```
public void createElement(T e) {

SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Log.e("path", db.getPath());
}

private String getCreationString() {
        List<String> fields = getFields();

        String createString = "create table if not exists " 
                + getTableName()
                + " ( " ;

        for (String field : fields) {
            createString = createString+ " " +field +" text "+ ",";
        }

        if (createString.length() > 0 && createString.charAt(createString.length()-1)==',') {
            createString = createString.substring(0, createString.length()-1);
        }
        createString=createString+ " );";
        return createString;
    }
    public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        //dropdatabase(database);
        database.execSQL(getCreationString());
    }


> 12-02 10:54:37.991: E/SQLiteLog(22945): (1) near "null": syntax error
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945): Error inserting  12-02
> 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error
> (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mandat(null) VALUES (NULL)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> Method) 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.facilogi.transellis.database.TransellisTable.createElement(TransellisTable.java:77)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.facilogi.transellis.backgroundTasks.BiensWebServiceTask.parse(BiensWebServiceTask.java:40)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.facilogi.transellis.backgroundTasks.BiensWebServiceTask.parse(BiensWebServiceTask.java:1)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.facilogi.transellis.backgroundTasks.Taskellis.doInBackground(Taskellis.java:132)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.facilogi.transellis.backgroundTasks.Taskellis.doInBackground(Taskellis.java:1)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> com.novoda.imageloader.core.loader.util.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:200)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 12-02
> 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
> 12-02 10:54:38.011: E/SQLiteDatabase(22945):  at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

the exception raised in

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
```

I don't believe it's this is the cause 
I don't realy know what can be the cause any help is appreciated 
thanks in advance .

Comment: did you initialize `helper`?

Comment: Your db is not opened at that point

Comment: I don't see an `insert()` call in the code you posted but it's there in your logcat. Possibly your code and sources are out of sync. Clean and rebuild first. Update the question with actual code if the problem persists.

Comment: I think that the problem was that i initialised the DatabaseHelper in the context.oncreate() ^^" 
can someone please confirm that dbHelper=new MyDatabaseHelper(this, tables);in context.oncreate() is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mandat(null) VALUES (NULL)
```

You forgot to put any values into your `ContentValues`.

Answer (score -2):

Before calling `SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();`

you should init `SqliteOpenHelper`

Statement like `dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(context);` should be executed .

Otherwise your databse will not get opened.

Comment: The database would not be able to return a syntax error if it were not open.